# Passing Arguments to ModelView edit template in flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I am trying to learn more about Flask by building a CMS. I am using flask-admin to add the posts, images etc.

I have managed to override  textarea with [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com). But I want to pass the paths of the images in the static folder to ckeditor image plugin.

I can't figure out how to pass parameters to my edit.html template.

Here's the code:

```
class TestAdmin(ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(text=forms.CustomTextAreaField)
    create_template = 'edit.html'
    edit_template = 'edit.html'
```

From the documentation of flask-admin I have found that `_template_args` can used to pass parameters to the template. But I can't figure out how.

What is the exact way to do that?

Answer (score 22):

You have to override the views to change `_template_args`.

```
class TestAdmin(ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(text=forms.CustomTextAreaField)
    create_template = 'edit.html'
    edit_template = 'edit.html'

    @expose('/edit/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def edit_view(self):
         self._template_args['foo'] = 'bar'
         return super(TestAdmin, self).edit_view()
```

If you want to pass some global value to templates, you can use a `context_processor` (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors).

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_paths():
    # you will be able to access {{ path1 }} and {{ path2 }} in templates
    return dict(path1='x', path2='y')
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar with index_view but it's not working at all. I keep getting the exception:
Exception: Attempted to instantiate admin view UserModelView without default view

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @JamieHush no idea, I can't help without some code. It should work if you subclass `AdminIndexView` and override `index` function.

Comment: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: @jul This answer is a bit old, maybe Flask-Admin changed some implementation detail. I really don't know why this code calls `index()` instead of `edit_view()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I guess `super(TestAdmin, self).edit_view()` should be returned, too.

Comment: @JamesHush you may forget to have a `@expose` at your index(self). this is how i got the same error as you did

Comment: The context processor method with global variables works well for me. I couldn't get the list view to work with template args. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

To anyone finding this in 2023+ – you can do it now by overriding `_get_list_extra_args` method:

```py
class YourView(ModelView):
    list_template = "custom_template.html"

    def _get_list_extra_args(self):
        view_args = super()._get_list_extra_args()
        view_args.extra_args["foo"] = "bar"
        return view_args
```

Here we can control `extra_args` dict. Flask-Admin's `index_view()` passes it straight to the template as is, so you can modify it and use it in `custom_template.html`:

```
<div>
    {{ extra_args.foo }}  {# will render "bar" #}
</div>
```