# Flask-Admin - custom view with original form

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I am trying to create a custom edit-view in Flask-Admin where I use the original edit form and add more content to it.

I want to use in my template the original:

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}
{% import 'admin/lib.html' as lib with context %}

(...)

{% block edit_form %}
    {{ lib.render_form(form, return_url, extra(), form_opts) }}
{% endblock %}
```

But I am having trouble passing the original form to the `self.render(...)` function in my custom view:

```
class MyView(sqla.ModelView):
    # (view options)

    @expose('/edit/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def edit_view(self):
        # (custom view variables)

        return self.render('my_edit_view.html')
```

I believe I have to pass some parameters in the `self.render` function. I tried to include a `form = form` but it didn't work (`TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable`)...

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714237/7811624

I believe the correct way to use the original form plus extra fields in a custom view  is:

```
class MyView(sqla.ModelView):
    # (view options)
    edit_template = 'my_edit_view.html'

    @expose('/edit/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def edit_view(self):
        # (custom view variables)
        # for the extra variables you wanna pass on to the template:
        self._template_args['foo'] = bar 

        return super(MyView, self).edit_view()
```